# why does making get request with empty string as search param results in returning random data instead of no data?

Tags: javascript, get

I am making a get request and I wonder if its normal that in the case that no search input was provided, I am still getting a response with random data? Making a get request to pixabay:

```
var API_KEY = '10677334-f0f7afbe90e1a76e6ab8380d7';
var URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+API_KEY+"&q="+encodeURIComponent('red roses'); //returns data as expected

var URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+API_KEY+"&q="+encodeURIComponent(''); //returns random data
```

I checked the network and in the case of empty string param, Im getting q=%20 for empty string. If I did JSON.stringify that it would somehow work (=not getting results) but my empty string turns into

```
q=%22%22 which does not seem right
```

Could anyone help and explain if I actually need to do something for that case or am I doing something completely wrong (it seems like that as strigifying etc does not seem like a typical solution) / shouldnt q= (with nothing provided in case of an empty string actually result in NOT giving me any data back?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I think this is a question to ask the providers of that service. Since the empty string matches any text, a random result seems arguably sensible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about behavior of a particular service.

Comment: i didnt know if its a behavior of that service provider or if I AM doing something wrong causing this behavior, thats why I asked.

Comment: Well one can imagine server software interpreting that empty string in all sorts of ways. Could be an error, could do what you're seeing, whatever; it's not an intrinsic result of any fundamental way that searching in a database works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a conscious decision on the part of the API developer.

For an answer to this, it's best to refer to the [pixabay.com API guide](https://www.pixabay.com/api/docs).

Note, regarding the 'q' param:

> A URL encoded search term. **If omitted, all images are returned**

Comment: Thank you very much, I didnt see that!!